# Does CMake take more memory than normal setup?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, cmake

I am just curious that: Does CMake take more memory than VS Code run & debug setup? and normal sln projects?

I recently checked that the size of the file is 4.18 MB, but the disk usage is 188 MB.

why?

Comment: Maybe it's enabled debug symbols?

Comment: Is VS *.sln a "normal" project? I could claim the reverse.

Comment: What do you mean with "file is 4.18 MB, but the disk usage is 188 MB"? which file and which disk usage?

Comment: Not the file, the entire folder: the build folder, which contain cmake instructions...

Comment: You are not going to ship the full build folder to the customer right? Just the binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake is tool build, testing and packaging automation tool. It is not a compiler!

The final executable size or performance does depend on the compiler, so it is independent of CMake (however not independent of what you setup in your CMakeLists.txt).

Why is your executable bigger while using CMake than Microsoft Visual Studio *.sln solution?

The reason is due to some difference in the build configuration:

- Debug (with symbols), vs Release
- Libraries linked statically or dynamically
- Optimization level and type
- Compiler used

Comment: The which one is the most optimal, which one is the least memory consuming and which one is the most user friendly?

Comment: There are so many factors that are more relevant than cache files disk space that it is difficult to answer. But if what you look is "which to use?", then think about this: with cmake you can generate VS project, but you can also generate Makefile or Ninja, XCode, etc.. Personally, as a Computer scientist/engineer, I don't want to be bound to the decisions and prices of a big corporate, neither my product/project/company.

Comment: I know, but i don't want to write codes that takes way more space and are inefficient.

Comment: not just the codes, but the compiler tooo

Comment: You are mixing compiler and project generation tool again: CMake does not build  your project and has ZERO impact on the size or efficiency of your binary/program. The efficiency/space of your program depends on the compiler and the configuration used to build (debug/release/optimizations/etc)

Comment: To push more on the difference: You can call the compiler in command line directly without *.sln neither cmake. This obviously become quickly tedious, so CMake helps you in  managing the project structure and creating scripts to build your project. But ultimately, the script calls the compiler and it is the compiler who produce the binary, smaller faster or not. If you care about binary space and size, then check compilers and it configuration/optimisation.

Comment: ok, but which tool build take less space, sorry we got sidetracked, but I wasn't looking for the compiler, just which build takes less space. because both came build and sln creates hundreds of megabytes of files.

Comment: Usually, as developer, you care about build quality (binary efficiency, security, space), eventually compilation time (time to compile). The project cache size, nobody care about, because they go to the trash, and if those several MB of files allows the build to be 10s faster, then it is worth (because your time as developer is costly). So to answer properly, why do you care about cache file size?

Comment: Make some assignment, and I don't want to make sln projects each of them

Comment: Sorry, still not clear to me what you want/need. You usually make the *sln project only once and use it. Same for *.cmake.

Comment: so one sln/cmake for every individual cpp files?

Comment: Please, explain your real problem with more than 10words, I can't guess. Usually one cmake/sln per project, or module.

Comment: Let continue this conversation on this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229929/does-cmake-take-more-memory-than-normal-setup

Comment: Sorry, i don't have that privilige to enter that right now.

Comment: I mean can one project execute multiple CPP files separately by selecting which one at the user's will?

Comment: *.cpp (C++ sources) are text files, you don't execute a source file. A compiler is used to translate a set of sources to a program (binary), which you send to the user/client. You can (as a dev) generate as many programs/binaries as you want, and the user/client can execute any of them at will. I would suggest you to read some good tutorial about it before your continue on the *sln/cmake topic. Just a gcc/clang compiler & notpad++ and make your "Hello World!" to understand the basics without the magics of the IDE.